# Mapstruct: How to map A extends SingleValue<T> to T and A extends SingleValue<T> to B extends SingleValue<T> with the same mapper?

Tags: java, generics, mapstruct

I've been staring at this problem for quite some time and have been unable to find a answer. I'm trying to use mapstruct to map objects that have fields that are implementations of a generic SingleValue objects.

Let me illustrate the problem with a simplified example. (throws are omitted for readability)

We have a Single Value object:

```
public abstract class SingleValue<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {
    private T value;

    public SingleValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

The concrete Single value class would look like this

```
public class FirstName extends SingleValue<String>{

}
```

And would be used in different objects that might be mapped to each other

Mappings that should be possible:

- String -> FirstName
- FirstName -> String
- FirstName -> another extends SingleValue object

The following mappings are possible with the current solution:

- String -> FirstName
- FirstName -> String

Current Single value mapper

```
@Mapper
public interface SingleValueMapper {
    SingleValueMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SingleValueMapper.class);
    default <Z extends Serializable, T extends SingleValue<Z>> T singleValue(Z obj, Class<Z> objClass, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return targetType.getConstructor(objClass).newInstance(obj);
    }

    default <T extends Serializable, Z extends SingleValue<T>> T getValue(Z singleValue) {
        if (singleValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return singleValue.getValue();
    }

    default <T extends SingleValue<String>> T singleValue(String obj, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        return singleValue(obj, String.class, targetType);

    }
}
```

For FirstName -> another extends SingleValue object mapping i came up with the following solution that did not work:

```
default <T extends SingleValue<String>> T stringSingleValue(SingleValue<String> obj, @TargetType Class<T> targetType)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    return singleValue(obj.getValue(), String.class, targetType);
}
```

Problems I have with mapping method mentioned above:

- Mapstruct will prefer the getValue(Z singleValue) mapping over this one in automatic selection (I really do not wan't to use Qualifiers because then i need to qualify each field that im mapping)
- Mapstruct will see the mapping method as ambiguous if we for instance also add one for UUID single values

works this call is generated by mapstruct when mapping a String to  A extends SingleValue:

```
A a = singleValueMapper.singleValue( client.getCompanyName(), A.class )
```

This call is not chosen by mapstruct but we can use it when manually use it with @Mapping as a expression. However we would like mapstruct to automatically map these calls when mapping A extends SingleValue to B extends SingleValue:

```
B b =singleValueMapper.stringSingleValue(command.getTitle(), B.class)
```

Is there a way to pull this off with mapstruct and java generics?

I'm using Mapstruct version 1.3.0-final.

Comment: which version of MapStruct are you using?

Comment: Version 1.3.0-final

Comment: It seems like your first method has 3 arguments.. `    default <Z extends Serializable, T extends SingleValue<Z>> T singleValue(Z obj, Class<Z> objClass, @TargetType Class<T> targetType)` MapStruct can only select mapping methods based on source / target.. Not on 2 sources. However, it can construct classes based on more than one sources.. is this what you intent? Is it in fact an `@ObjectFactory`?

Comment: its hard to help you on this case.. Could you also provide the calling mapper to this example.?

Comment: @Sjaak While answering your question I realised there is a fault in my Question the solution i thought of but didn't work wasn't the right code snippet i fixed this in the question. The method with 3 arguments is never called by other mappers outside of the SingleValueMapper. it's only called  methods with 2 arguments in the example above that would be 'default <T extends SingleValue<String>> T singleValue(String obj, '@'TargetType Class<T> targetType)' method. I've added examples of calls and some descriptive text to the question

Comment: Could you try to test against the latest master? I recently fixed an issue with ambiguous method. Note that was only a wrong error message but it puts one on the wrong track

Answer (score 0):

I need some place to give some feedback.

```
@Mapper // Why is this annotated with @Mapper or even an interface (iso a regular class)? Are there more methods in here not shown that should be generated by MapStruct?
public interface SingleValueMapper {
    SingleValueMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(SingleValueMapper.class);

    // How should MapStruct know how to populate these? It can only map a source to a target? It takes @TargetType as hint, but it cannot populate the second argument Class<Z> ojbClass. But is this required? Perhaps obj.getClass()? 
    default <Z extends Serializable, T extends SingleValue<Z>> T singleValue(Z obj, Class<Z> objClass, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return targetType.getConstructor(objClass).newInstance(obj);
    }

    default <T extends Serializable, Z extends SingleValue<T>> T getValue(Z singleValue) {
        if (singleValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return singleValue.getValue();
    }

    // seems to me like a duplicate of the above?
    default <T extends SingleValue<String>> T singleValue(String obj, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        return singleValue(obj, String.class, targetType);

    }
}
```

So with the above, I would rewrite this class like this:

```java
public class SingleValueMapper {

    <Z extends Serializable, T extends SingleValue<Z>> T singleValue(Z obj,  @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return targetType.getConstructor(obj.getClass()).newInstance(obj);
    }

    <T extends Serializable, Z extends SingleValue<T>> T getValue(Z singleValue) {
        if (singleValue == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return singleValue.getValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sjaak je bent een held :). This simplifies allot which is great. However with this solution I still get errors when mapping A extends SingleValue<String> to B extends SingleValue<String>. The error i get is that there is Ambiguous mapping between the getValue() and the singleValue() methods. Is there any way to solve this problem without using Qualifiers? (Because that would mean we would mean we need to use qualifiers almost everywhere because we have allot of single value mappings)

Comment: when you take the generics away, the resulting methods are: `SingleValue singleValue(Serializable obj @TargetType Class<Singlevalue> targetType)` and ` Serializable getValue( SingleValue singleValue)` Right? The problem is that `SingleValue` is also `Serializable`.. Perhaps you need a different marker interface to express the value of a `SingleValue`. Both candidates are fit for mapping wrt to MapStruct. You might however play with `@Mapping#resultType`..